# Listings with rule above caption to look like \floatstyle{ruled}

Tags: listings, rules

I am using the `listings` package.

I would like my listings to have a heavy rule above the caption, so it looks like the `\floatstyle{ruled}`.

So it would look like:

> a bold line ===
>
> caption
>
> rule ---
>
> code
>
> rule ---

Comment: Give a example file. I will give a solution

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please keep in mind that it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Basically, show some work by getting the example as far as you can.

Answer (score 7):

The packages `listings` provides the option `frame=single` which draws a single line above and below the environment itself. So you have to add a single bold line before the caption is set. Therefore I am using the command `pretocmd` provided by `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\lstset{frame=lines}
\pretocmd\lst@makecaption{\noindent{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some Caption}]
    static uint64_t i = 0;
    void every_cycle()
    {
        if (i > 0)
            i--;
    }

        uint64_t next_num()
    {
        return (i += 0x100);
    }
\end{lstlisting}
Text
\begin{lstlisting}
    static uint64_t i = 0;
    void every_cycle()
    {
        if (i > 0)
            i--;
    }

        uint64_t next_num()
    {
        return (i += 0x100);
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `ruled` style this way:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{code}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{code}{Listing}
\numberwithin{code}{chapter}
```

Then do `\begin{code} ... \end{code}` around the listing instead of `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`.